# Accessibility and links that are buttons and vice versa

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

Can someone advise me if there is a specific WCAG 2.1 failure when buttons are used as links. Same question vice versa. Links as buttons.

I have a site i am working on where by design there are links that appear the same as the buttons do. 
So you may have buttons `<button>` like:
Edit details - which takes you to a new page where you can edit items in the page where the "edit details resides".
Continue - a button that takes you to the next page in a series of pages.
But then have links `<a>` which appear as buttons, so the same style, but they are labelled select, select and selected and these are a product type, so do not link anywhere.
Another example is the back link is a button`<button>` but looks like a link (text with underlined style)!

I know that this behavior confuses voice recognition as the user says `click link` or `click button`and not all objects get flagged that appear the same.

My question is does this fail WCAG2.1 specifically? Would this fall under 4.1.2 Name, Role, Value?

Answer (score 2):

The [4.1.2: Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/name-role-value.html) undestanding addresses the case of elements having different role than usual.

> If custom controls are created, however, or interface elements are programmed (in code or script) **to have a different role and/or function than usual**, then additional measures need to be taken to ensure that the controls provide important information to assistive technologies and allow themselves to be controlled by assistive technologies.

Comment: what do you do about a visually looking button, that has been programmed as a button but now to meet 4.1.2 has a role of link because of its function?

Comment: keep pressing enter for new line and submitting!! isnt it still failing due to its appearance?

Comment: This goes against [First and second rules of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#NOTES) but [this is not forbidden](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#document-conformance-requirements-for-use-of-aria-attributes-in-html) if it's [correctly implemented](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/button/button.html)

Answer (score 2):

As [Adam already cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59907632/10551549), "additional measures need to be taken to ensure that the controls provide important information to assistive technologies and allow themselves to be controlled by assistive technologies". So yes, this fails WCAG 2.1, unless you take measures to ensure that your button-links and link-buttons really work as they are supposed to **for example** that a `<a role="button" […]` can be triggered using the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

If you *really* have accessibility in mind, don't mix `<button>` and `<a>` elements up. Not even if you think you are smart and add `role="button"` to a link or `role="link` to a button. You would have to do more than that to make them behave like each other (see [MDN about the button role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role#Accessibility_concerns)).
And even then you should consider this: links are for navigation, buttons for performing actions. If you have a navigational element that looks like a button, its behavior might be confusing (even if it has no `role="button"` attribute). Also note that the default value for a button's `type` attribute is `submit` ("[The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element)").

Web accessibility should [encompass all disabilities that affect access to the Web](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/#what) and there are a lot of possible disabilities – and having one disability does not necessarily mean a person has no other disabilities.
The easiest step of making your website more accessible is to stick to the standards. Don't change an element's behavior unless you really have to (and even then: do you *really* have to?).

**Update: General comment about WCAG and accessibility:**
Web accessibility is also not just about simply conforming to guidelines like the WCAG. Even the WCAG itself does not claim that a website will be 100% accessible when conforming to it:

> Note that even content that conforms at the highest level (AAA) will not be accessible to individuals with all types, degrees, or combinations of disability, particularly in the cognitive language and learning areas. Authors are encouraged to consider the full range of techniques, including the advisory techniques, as well as to seek relevant advice about current best practice to ensure that Web content is accessible, as far as possible, to this community.

**Update: Examples of possible violations of WCAG 2.1 (with room for interpretation though)**
Just letting links look like buttons and nothing could be failing:

- [Guideline 3.2 Predictable](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#predictable) in general ("Make Web pages appear and operate in predictable ways.")
- [Success Criterion 3.2.4 Consistent Identification](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#x3-2-4-consistent-identification) (unless *all* links look like buttons; **the only actual success criterion in these examples**)
- [4. Robust](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#robust) in general ("Content must be robust enough that it can be interpreted by by a wide variety of user agents, including assistive technologies." & [Guideline 4.1 Compatible](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#compatible) "Maximize compatibility with current and future user agents, including assistive technologies." --> you already mentioned voice recognition and the possibility of not being able to target a link because it looks like a button)
- Jonathan Pool wrote [a blog article about this issue](https://jpdev.pro/blog/entries/3/) in which he points out another possible violation:

  > Worst case: A button that takes an irreversible action ("Yes, I confirm that I am waiving my rights.") pretends to be a link, so the user tries to use SPACE or SHIFT-SPACE to scroll the page but unexpectedly presses the button. This, arguably, would violate [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.1 Success Criterion 3.3.4.](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#error-prevention-legal-financial-data)

Comment: Thank you for adding your comments. Something still isn't clear.
My question is does it matter is they are visually confusing. I would say yes in terms of cognitive and voice recognition users.
If a link that navigates somewhere is a rounded cornered square with text in the square but a button also is a rounded cornered square with text in the square. Both programmed correctly for their purpose but visually confusing, can i, under WCAG2.1 say they must change that link to look like a link and not look like a button?

Comment: i am happy with elements serving the purpose that they are designed for but its the styling guys i want/ need to steer and need to know that i can wave the WCAG stick at them when they are reluctant to change their design.

Comment: essentially these guys seem to like using rounded squares as links but also for buttons.

Comment: @user2007920 I've edited my answer. Regarding "stick[ing] [WCAG] at them" you should especially note: "Web accessibility is also not just about simply conforming to guidelines like the WCAG."

Comment: A button that seems to be a link can be a violation of WCAG 2.1 Success Criterion 3.3.4, in addition to tthose mentioned above. See https://jpdev.pro/blog/entries/3/.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point! I have added the example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

use role="button" that will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For WCAG in cases where there is `button` used as `link` or `link` used as `button` you have to add `role="button"`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).